# Appending a string before an HTML Element

Tags: javascript, dom, leaflet

I am able to create an input field in a Leaflet popup that edits a GeoJSON property by following the solution posted here:

[Edit feature attributes in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834401/edit-feature-attributes-in-leaflet)

I would like to add a constant string in the popup, so that the popup reads something like, 'EDIT YOUR DATA HERE: [input with editable data]'

When I try to do this the input box fails and returns the string '[object HTMLInputElement]' instead.

How to avoid this?

```js
var input = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'my-input');

input.value = feature.properties.datatoedit;
L.DomEvent.addListener(input, 'change', function() {
  feature.properties.datatoedit = input.value;
});

var popupcontent = "<b>Edit Data Here: </b><br>" + input;

layer.bindPopup(popupcontent);
```

Comment: I'm going to leave a comment as opposed to an answer as I'm not familiar with leaflet. You create `input` as a DOM element. Note that this is not a string so are trying to concatenate a string with a DOM element. Hence your result. Create your string as a DOM element and work with that. Perhaps wrap your elements in and additional DOM container like a `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

You have to realize that `"<b>Edit Data Here: </b><br>" + input` is trying to concatenate a *string* with an *HTML Element*.

When doing so, the JS engine will try to cast `input` into a string, which renders your `'[object HTMLInputElement]'` string.

Instead, you should convert your `"<b>Edit Data Here: </b><br>"` part as an HTML Element (could be a fragment as well), so that you can insert it alongside your `input` and provide them as HTML nodes for your popup content.

```js
// Create an HTML Element container for both your string and input.
var popupContent = document.createElement('div');

// Fill it first with your raw HTML code.
// It will automatically be parsed and converted as HTML nodes.
popupContent.innerHTML = "<b>Edit Data Here: </b><br>";

// Now you can append your `input` which is already an HTML Element.
popupContent.appendChild(input);

layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/W11Z95Y9dQZThBu2dKQz?p=preview

Comment: I was going to go down a similar path to this, but I'll suggest a couple of possible "improvements". I was going to create a `label` element for the `input`as that seems to make sense in this instance.

Comment: @JonP yes there is always room for improvement! :-) please feel free to offer some guidance to OP, might even be through a new answer.